# RNA-seq, HISAT2で エラー”hisat2-align died with signal 6”

Tags: bioinformatics

RNA-seqデータ解析初心者です。環境：MacOS、メモリ32GB使用
トリミング後のリードをHISAT2でマッピングしました。

```
hisat2 -q -p 4 --dta -x ./ref38/genome \
-1 ./data02/SRRxxxx_1_trimmed.fq \
-2 ./data02/SRRxxxx_2_trimmed.fq \
-S ./data02/lung_SRRxxxx.sam
```

エラー

```
Error, fewer reads in file specified with -2 than in file specified with -1
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type int
(ERR): hisat2-align died with signal 6 (ABRT)
```

上記のエラーはコアダンプようですが、55GBのsamファイルは生成されています。
マッピングは成功しているのでしょうか？
どなたかご教示くださるとたすかります。

Comment: hisat2 のソースコードを読むと、最初の "fewer reads ..." は paired-end read なのに unpair な read が存在する、というエラーです。fastq から unpair read を除去する必要がありそうです。

Comment: ソースコードの解読、ありがとうございました！unpairなリードがfastqにあるんですね。一先ず、別のパッケージでトリミングしたデータでマッピングして、同じエラーがでたらunpairリードの除去を試みます。

Comment: Trim GaloreでトリミングしたデータからTrimmomaticのデータに変えたら解析できました。ありがとうございました。